# mysql count group by having

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have this table:

```
Movies (ID, Genre)
```

A movie can have multiple genres, so an ID is not specific to a genre, it is a many to many relationship. I want a query to find the total number of movies which have at exactly 4 genres. The current query I have is

```
  SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM Movies 
GROUP BY ID 
  HAVING COUNT(Genre) = 4
```

However, this returns me a list of 4's instead of the total sum. How do I get the sum total sum instead of a list of `count(*)`?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

One way would be to use a nested query:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM (
   SELECT COUNT(Genre) AS count
   FROM movies
   GROUP BY ID
   HAVING (count = 4)
) AS x
```

The inner query gets all the movies that have exactly 4 genres, then outer query counts how many rows the inner query returned.

Comment: Then how effectively to calculate percentage of movies that have exactly 4 genres over total count of all movies?

Comment: @stuckedoverflow divide it by the number of rows? Instead of `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM...` at the beginning write `SELECT COUNT(*) / (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ID) FROM movies) FROM ...`

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM   (SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM   movies 
        GROUP  BY id 
        HAVING COUNT(genre) = 4) t
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe

```
SELECT count(*) FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Movies GROUP BY ID HAVING count(Genre) = 4
) AS the_count_total
```

although that would not be the sum of all the movies, just how many have 4 genre's.

So maybe you want

```
SELECT sum(
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Movies GROUP BY ID having Count(Genre) = 4
) as the_sum_total
```

Comment: I updated it again (v1) to have an alias for the statment otherwise  one gets `Every derived table must have its own alias`

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT ID FROM Movies GROUP BY ID HAVING COUNT(Genre)=4) a
```

Comment: What is the last 'a' supposed to do ?

Comment: @EricVB It´s a column alias for the result. MySQL allows (yet) to omit the keyword `AS`.