# SQL - count each column where each column = 1

Tags: mysql

I want to count teacher, organizer, administrator group by organization.

This is my current DB example:

[image]

Expected result will be:

```
teacher | organizer | administrator | organization_id
---------------------------------------------------
    1   |   1       |       1       |       6035
    5   |   4       |       1       |       12554
```

and what I've tried so far

```
SELECT
    count(teacher),
    count(organizer),
    count(administrator),
    organization_id
FROM users
WHERE
    teacher = 1
AND organizer = 1
AND administrator = 1
GROUP BY organization_id;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql count group by having](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857538/mysql-count-group-by-having)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cause your column value is 0/1, so you can just use `SUM` to count nums:

```
SELECT
    SUM(teacher) as teacher,
    SUM(organizer) as organizer,
    SUM(administrator)as administrator,
    organization_id
FROM users GROUP BY organization_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your expected result, I think you should use `or` rather than `and` in your `where` statement.

```
SELECT
    count(teacher),
    count(organizer),
    count(administrator),
    organization_id
FROM users
WHERE
    teacher = 1
or organizer = 1
or administrator = 1
GROUP BY organization_id;
```